# js rendering a lot of html using json

Tags: javascript, templates

I make a call to my api and returns json objects, then it generates a lot of divs full of content. But i keep using concatenation to insert my object properties. Is there a better way to to that?

```
$.each(JSON, function(key, value) { 
  var content = display_mention(value);
  $("#mentions_container").append(content);
    });

    function display_mention(mention) {
       //this str will be much more complex and use lots of concatenation
   var str = "<div data-id='" + mention.id +"'> " + mention.texto + "</div></br>";
   return str;
    }
```

Comment: If you do it on your own (that is without a template engine) concatenating the html string and appending it once in the end is the most efficient solution regarding rendering speed. However, you could use jQuery templates, dust, mustache or similar if you generate lots of html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way and it's called client side templating.

Look at mustache.js https://github.com/janl/mustache.js
or handlebars.js http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

I like using this guy as microtemplate engine:

```
String.prototype.tpl = function(o) {
    return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
        function(a, b) {
            var r = o[b];
            if (!o[b]) return "";
            return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
        }
    );
};

var data = {
  title: 'C pocket reference',
  type: 'PDF Document',
  tag: 'programming',
  created_at: '5.31.2010'
}

var html = '<tr><td>{title2}</td><td>{type}</td><td><a href="tags/{tag}">{tag}</a></td><td>{created_at}</td></tr>'.tpl(data);
```

It's very simple but it will make your code cleaner.

But you should definetely to look at more serious solutions like: [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) (sine you use jQuery) or select some other from here http://microjs.com/#templating

Comment: yeah defenitely helps a lot when u need simple interpolation... mustach helps too.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple template function if you do not need a bigger engine.

```
function template(str, context) {
    return str.replace(/\{([a-z]+)\}/g, function(match, key) {
        return context[key];
    });
}
```

You just call it with an object context like this:

```
template("<div data-id='{id}'> {texto}</div></br>", mention);
```

Comment: yes i'll trade mustach to this approach if it helps the performance, because the client is mobile.

Comment: We use [dust.js](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) sucessfully on mobile. But if you don't need all the features like conditionals and loops, maybe look into [underscore template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) to get some ideas how to do it more robust.